# Accessing parent daemon from container in Jenkins

Tags: docker, jenkins

We have a bunch of nodes running our jobs in Jenkins. I have the need to build two images from a Jenkins job. To do this, I've read that you should share the unix socket using bind mounting, and I've done that like this:

```
agent {
    docker {
        image 'custom-alpine-with-docker'
        args '-v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock'
    }
}
```

I then want to use it as follows:

```
stage('Build and push image(s)') {
    steps {
        dir("${WORKING_DIRECTORY}") {
            script {
                echo 'Building amd64 image'
                amd64image = docker.build("${IMAGE_NAME}:${BUILD_NUMBER}-amd64", "-f ./Dockerfile.amd64 .")
                echo 'Building arm32v7 image'
                arm32v7image = docker.build("${IMAGE_NAME}:${BUILD_NUMBER}-arm32v7", "-f ./Dockerfile.arm32v7 .")
            }
            script {
                docker.withRegistry("${DOCKER_REGISTRY_URL}", "${REPOSITORY_CREDENTIALS}") {
                    amd64image.push()
                    arm32v7image.push()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, as soon as the build command is issued in the jenkins job, I get the following error:

> time="2019-01-16T16:55:33Z" level=error msg="failed to dial gRPC: cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is 'docker daemon' running on this host?: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied"
>   17:56:59 Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock:

So a simple search shows the source of this error is that the user trying to access the daemon is not in the docker group, but I don't understand how these group memberships work when sharing a daemon like this.

If I go to the node that failed the build, and check the users in the docker group, I get the following:

```
$ getent group docker
docker:x:126:inst,jenkins
```

So how do I allow the user running in the container on that host to access the same daemon?

**Small update**

Just did it locally using `docker run -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -ti docker`, and when I write `docker ps` in the container and on my host I see the same containers running.

Getting all the users on my development machine, it looks like this:

```
docker:x:999:overlord
```

So I'm guessing I need some special jenkins solution for this to work..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've solved this in satisfactory way. Here's a step-by-step guide:

1. Ensure docker is installed in the container that needs to run it
2. Create the docker group and jenkins user:

```
CMD DOCKER_GID=$(stat -c '%g' /var/run/docker.sock) && \
    groupmod --gid ${DOCKER_GID} ${DOCKER_GROUP} && \
    usermod -a -G ${DOCKER_GROUP} ${JENKINS_USER} && \
    gosu jenkins sh
```

It is important to note that here I fetch the group Id of the underlying system that runs docker. As I had already installed docker in my container and the group already existed, I modify the existing group to match the group id of the system. Finally I add the jenkins user to the docker group. Your /etc/group should look something like this in the container after it's run:

docker:x:999:jenkins

3. In your pipeline, start the agent as follows:

```
agent {
    docker {
        image 'storemanager-build'
        args '-u root -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock'
    }
}
```

By supplying the `-u root` flag, you override the user `jenkins` that jenkins forces on you when you use the declarative pipeline. You have to use root for the CMD command to work and to be able to create the group.

When the image is running, the command will switch to a jenkins user that is allowed to access the underlying unix socket.

Here's an excerpt fro my Jenkinsfile:

```
pipeline {

    agent {
        docker {
            image 'build-image'
            args '-u root -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock'
        }
    }

    stages {

        stage('Build jar') {
            steps {
                dir("${WORKING_DIRECTORY}") {
                    script {
                        if (isUnix()) {
                            sh './mvnw --batch-mode clean install'
                        } else {
                            bat 'mvnw.cmd --batch-mode clean install'
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        stage('Build and push image(s)') {
            steps {
                dir("${WORKING_DIRECTORY}") {
                    script {
                        amd64image = docker.build("${IMAGE_NAME}", "-f ./Dockerfile.amd64 .")
                        arm32v7image = docker.build("${IMAGE_NAME}", "-f ./Dockerfile.arm32v7 .")
                    }
                    script {
                        docker.withRegistry("${DOCKER_REGISTRY_URL}", "${STOREMANAGER_REPOSITORY_CREDENTIALS}") {
                            amd64image.push("${BUILD_NUMBER}-amd64")
                            arm32v7image.push("${BUILD_NUMBER}-arm32v7")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    post {
        always {
            sh "chmod -R 777 ." // Jenkins can't clean built resources without this as we run the container as root
            cleanWs()
        }
    }
}
```

And the resources that helped me:

https://jpetazzo.github.io/2015/09/03/do-not-use-docker-in-docker-for-ci/
https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker/issues/196

Hope this helps.